# Smooth Scroll in ScrollSpy

Tags: javascript, html, web, bootstrap-4, vs-web-site-project

Sorry for my English.

I'm creating a website, and I want to implement smooth scroll for internal links. I have tried many different codes, `html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}`, and different JavaScript codes.

The horizontal navbar works fine with those codes:

[image: screen shot of web page]

But the vertical navbar, which works as *scrollspy*, doesn't work with smooth scroll.

[image: screen shot of web page]

This is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-bt">
<head>
  <script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title> Curso HTML Bootstrap </title>
  <!--Requeried Meta TAGS!-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-gradient-primary">

  <div class="container">

    <a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0" href="#">Curso</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSite">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#item3">Inicio</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Depoimentos</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contatos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
             id="navDrop">Redes Sociais</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Facebook</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Instagram</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Youtube</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Linkedin</a>
          </div>

        </li>

      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control ml-4" type="search"
               placeholder="Pesquisar...">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Ok</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="2"></li>

  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/idaho239691_1920.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          Aliquam commodo dolor a ligula fringilla laoreet. Sed sagittis
          eleifend sem, eget pretium est aliquam sit amet. Vivamus at
          consectetur felis. Proin eu accumsan lectus. Etiam id ante at ex
          tempor iaculis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/img (35).jpg" class="d-block w-100">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h1>Etiam ac elit et eros consequat luctus.</h1>
        <p class="lead">Etiam ac elit et eros consequat luctus. Phasellus eu
          sapien molestie, pharetra odio ac, mollis turpis. Mauris aliquam arcu
          in orci accumsan, et semper mi lacinia.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/maxresdefault.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h1>Phasellus tempus eget enim vel pharetra.</h1>
        <p class="lead">Phasellus tempus eget enim vel pharetra. Aliquam erat
          volutpat. Mauris vehicula lectus quis tellus semper pretium vitae a
          purus. Ut vulputate quam eget tincidunt efficitur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselSite" role="button"
     data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselSite" role="button"
     data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Avançar</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center my-5">
      <h1 class="display-3">Maecenas orci risus</h1>
      <p>Maecenas orci risus, consequat eu luctus vehicula, vulputate sit amet
        arcu.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <nav id="navbarVertical" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#item1">Lorem ipsum</a>
          <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <a class="nav-link ml-3" href="#item1-1">Curabitur bibendum</a>
            <a class="nav-link ml-3" href="#item1-2">Phasellus posuere</a>
          </nav>
          <a class="nav-link my-2" href="#item2">Sed feugiat</a>
          <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <a class="nav-link ml-3" href="#item2-1">Aliquam ac</a>
            <a class="nav-link ml-3" href="#item2-2">Maecenas eleifend</a>
          </nav>
          <a class="nav-link my-2" href="#item3">Nunc vitae</a>
          <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <a class="nav-link ml-3" href="#item3-1">Duis nec orci</a>
            <a class="nav-link ml-3" href="#item3-2">Ut imperdiet</a>
          </nav>
        </nav>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-9">
      <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbarVertical" data-offset="0"
           class="scrollspySite">
        <h4 id="item1">Lorem ipsum</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam
          venenatis tortor fermentum ullamcorper laoreet. Fusce fermentum nibh
          sed lacus euismod tincidunt. Aliquam lorem turpis, condimentum id
          augue ut, aliquet pretium eros. In id neque mi. Fusce semper magna
          eget pharetra porta. Donec auctor scelerisque nisi, eleifend rhoncus
          lectus suscipit quis. Etiam scelerisque feugiat varius. Maecenas sed
          malesuada mi. Pellentesque sit amet dolor aliquet, imperdiet odio
          vitae, suscipit dolor. Aliquam ullamcorper eros ac justo volutpat, nec
          lacinia metus tempus. Morbi at odio vestibulum, scelerisque mauris in,
          laoreet massa. Praesent consectetur eros quis dapibus pharetra.</p>
        <h5 id="item1-1">Teste</h5>
        <p>Vestibulum mollis lacus quis dolor sodales, sit amet vestibulum
          tellus aliquet. Fusce ultrices quis mauris non placerat. Maecenas
          dolor velit, tincidunt rutrum sapien vitae, cursus vestibulum dui.
          Quisque in dignissim arcu, vitae porttitor velit. Mauris tempus
          ullamcorper orci ut dictum. Curabitur commodo dolor ac dui accumsan,
          luctus tincidunt nisl pulvinar. Donec est ipsum, lobortis id lorem sit
          amet, vulputate blandit nisl. Nunc viverra pulvinar neque. Orci varius
          natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
          mus. Curabitur sed sem ac velit lobortis porta. Proin blandit turpis
          diam, non consectetur lectus iaculis molestie. Fusce venenatis, erat a
          venenatis vehicula, libero sapien molestie dui, ac aliquet risus nisi
          at orci.</p>iquet. Fusce ultrices quis mauris non placerat. Maecenas
        dolor velit, tincidunt rutrum sapien vitae, cursus vestibulum dui.
        Quisque in dignissim arcu, vitae porttitor velit. Mauris tempus
        ullamcorper orci ut dictum. Curabitur commodo dolor ac dui accumsan,
        luctus tincidunt nisl pulvinar. Donec est ipsum, lobortis id lorem sit
        amet, vulputate blandit nisl. Nunc viverra pulvinar neque. Orci varius
        natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
        mus. Curabitur sed sem ac velit lobortis porta. Proin blandit turpis
        diam, non consectetur lectus iaculis molestie. Fusce venenatis, erat a
        venenatis vehicula, libero sapien molestie dui, ac aliquet risus nisi at
        orci.</p>
        <h5 id="item1-2">Aliquam at</h5>
        <p>Aliquam at enim tincidunt, fringilla purus at, lacinia ipsum. Aenean
          sed convallis elit, eu hendrerit urna. Praesent hendrerit dui non
          vulputate lobortis. Praesent tempor tellus in ultricies gravida.
          Nullam bibendum bibendum justo eget pulvinar. Suspendisse gravida
          tristique tristique. Nulla tincidunt nibh et luctus mollis. Praesent
          nunc ipsum, porttitor nec quam non, eleifend bibendum elit. Vestibulum
          dui dui, suscipit sit amet consequat ut, sagittis eu libero. Duis
          tempus luctus lobortis. Maecenas consectetur finibus porta.</p>

        <h4 id="item2">Sed varius</h4>
        <p>Sed varius augue in velit lobortis ultricies. Donec auctor vitae
          justo quis laoreet. Sed ac tellus metus. Nunc non mauris est. Interdum
          et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras turpis
          justo, lobortis et cursus in, mattis at est. Sed lorem enim, dignissim
          at sem vitae, mattis porttitor turpis. Nunc ac eleifend orci, et
          tincidunt sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et
          netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur placerat varius
          aliquet. Nullam sit amet velit laoreet, accumsan purus at, molestie
          est. Aenean sodales turpis vel egestas dapibus. Mauris fringilla at
          eros quis blandit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
          conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed convallis nisi fermentum
          varius tincidunt.</p>
        <h5 id="item2-1">Ut scelerisque</h5>
        <p>Ut scelerisque neque sed nunc porttitor, ut egestas metus accumsan.
          Proin quis odio nec ex fringilla cursus. Quisque faucibus dictum
          risus, vitae porttitor felis varius ac. Etiam sit amet gravida felis,
          sed porta velit. Etiam rhoncus egestas maximus. Quisque mollis, elit
          eu ultricies luctus, velit mi congue nisi, iaculis congue massa risus
          vitae lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
        <h5 id="item2-2">Lorem ipsum</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam
          venenatis tortor fermentum ullamcorper laoreet. Fusce fermentum nibh
          sed lacus euismod tincidunt. Aliquam lorem turpis, condimentum id
          augue ut, aliquet pretium eros. In id neque mi. Fusce semper magna
          eget pharetra porta. Donec auctor scelerisque nisi, eleifend rhoncus
          lectus suscipit quis. Etiam scelerisque feugiat varius. Maecenas sed
          malesuada mi. Pellentesque sit amet dolor aliquet, imperdiet odio
          vitae, suscipit dolor. Aliquam ullamcorper eros ac justo volutpat, nec
          lacinia metus tempus. Morbi at odio vestibulum, scelerisque mauris in,
          laoreet massa. Praesent consectetur eros quis dapibus pharetra.</p>

        <h4 id="item3">Vestibulum mollis</h4>
        <p>Vestibulum mollis lacus quis dolor sodales, sit amet vestibulum
          tellus aliquet. Fusce ultrices quis mauris non placerat. Maecenas
          dolor velit, tincidunt rutrum sapien vitae, cursus vestibulum dui.
          Quisque in dignissim arcu, vitae porttitor velit. Mauris tempus
          ullamcorper orci ut dictum. Curabitur commodo dolor ac dui accumsan,
          luctus tincidunt nisl pulvinar. Donec est ipsum, lobortis id lorem sit
          amet, vulputate blandit nisl. Nunc viverra pulvinar neque. Orci varius
          natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
          mus. Curabitur sed sem ac velit lobortis porta. Proin blandit turpis
          diam, non consectetur lectus iaculis molestie. Fusce venenatis, erat a
          venenatis vehicula, libero sapien molestie dui, ac aliquet risus nisi
          at orci.estibulum mollis lacus quis dolor sodales, sit amet vestibulum
          tellus aliquet. Fusce ultrices quis mauris non placerat. Maecenas
          dolor velit, tincidunt rutrum sapien vitae, cursus vestibulum dui.
          Quisque in dignissim arcu, vitae porttitor velit. Mauris tempus
          ullamcorper orci ut dictum. Curabitur commodo dolor ac dui accumsan,
          luctus tincidunt nisl pulvinar. Donec est ipsum, lobortis id lorem sit
          amet, vulputate blandit nisl. Nunc viverra pulvinar neque. Orci varius
          natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
          mus. Curabitur sed sem ac velit lobortis porta. Proin blandit turpis
          diam, non consectetur lectus iaculis molestie. Fusce venenatis, erat a
          venenatis vehicula, libero sapien molestie dui, ac aliquet risus nisi
          at orci.</p>
        <h5 id="item3-1">Aliquam at</h5>
        <p> raesent tempor tellus in ultricies gravida. Nullam bibendum bibendum
          justo eget pulvinar. Su Praesent tempor tellus in ultricies gravida.
          Nullam bibendum bibendum justo eget pulvinar. Suspendisse gravida
          tristique tristique. Nulla tincidunt nibh et luctus mollis. Praesent
          nunc ipsum, porttitor nec quam non, eleifend bibendum elit. Vestibulum
          dui dui, suscipit sit amet consequat ut, sagittis eu libero. Duis
          tempus luctus lobortis. Maecenas consectetur finibus porta. liquam at
          enim tincidunt, fringilla purus at, lacinia ipsum. Aenean sed
          convallis elit, eu hendrerit urna. Praesent hendrerit dui non
          vulputate lobortis. Praesent tempor tellus in ultricies gravida.
          Nullam bibendum bibendum justo eget pulvinar. Suspendisse gravida
          tristique tristique. Nulla tincidunt nibh et luctus mollis. Praesent
          nunc ipsum, porttitor nec quam non, eleifend bibendum elit. Vestibulum
          dui dui, suscipit sit amet consequat ut, sagittis eu libero. Duis
          tempus luctus lobortis. Maecenas consectetur finibus porta</p>
        <h5 id="item3-2">Sed varius</h5>
        <p>Sed varius augue in velit lobortis ultricies. Donec auctor vitae
          justo quis laoreet. Sed ac tellus metus. Nunc non mauris est. Interdum
          et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras turpis
          justo, lobortis et cursus in, mattis at est. Sed lorem enim, dignissim
          at sem vitae, mattis porttitor turpis. Nunc ac eleifend orci, et
          tincidunt sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et
          netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur placerat varius
          aliquet. Nullam sit amet velit laoreet, accumsan purus at, molestie
          est. Aenean sodales turpis vel egestas dapibus. Mauris fringilla at
          eros quis blandit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
          conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed convallis nisi fermentum
          varius tincidunt.</p>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery first, then popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my styles.scss is:

```
.scrollspySite{
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 400px;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```